# bootstrap set asp grid width based on media

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web page that has several bootstrap rows and one of the rows contains an asp.net grid.
I need the **grid width to not shrink below 800px** and add **horizontal scroll bar** if the **client view shrinks below 800px**.
For example I would do the following to for all clients to use 400px width and then it would auto scroll the grid.

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto;width:400px;overflow:scroll">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="1280px">
        <%-- GRID STUFF HERE --%>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

I would like some way of NOT hard coding the width of the div to 400px.

**EDIT**
I am using bootstrap like the following example.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row" id="testGrid" style="overflow-x:auto;width:400px;">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="1280px">
                <%-- GRID STUFF HERE --%>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there anything in bootstrap that I can use to help?
Am I even using bootstrap correctly by placing the grid in a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A media query should do the trick. Use a selector on your row and target that based on the clients view size. [Hope this helps.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Using @media (max-width:1280px) helped me get what I needed. I only set the overflow-x:auto when with the above media tag. I did have to set the style="width:100%" on the row div to get it all to work correctly.